# dmesg errors: usb, EXT4, ath3k

Tags: boot

On Debian 8, whenever I run after boot

```
dmesg | grep error
```

I get

```
[    1.226156] usb 1-4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22

[    1.431774] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

[    1.623611] usb 1-4: Direct firmware load failed with error -2

[    1.628498] ath3k: probe of 1-4:1.0 failed with error -12

[    1.773358] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Can anyone comment on these errors? It seems they do not affect the system (even if I suspect the boot to be slighter slow because of them)

I do not know if this is a useful piece of information but I have powertop running at startup (all set to good).

Edit1:
Output of

```
    lsusb -t

    /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Edit 2:

I installed firmware-atheros now

```
    dmesg | grep error
```

is limited to

```
    [    1.234204] usb 1-4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
    [    1.431215] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 2 and 5 (both lines starting with `EXT4`): These lines only show mount options and no errors.

Other lines: Use `lsusb -t` to find what device is causing the error - edit your question and add the output. Line 3 and 4 are most probably the result of the error from line 1.

I expect this to be a bluetooth-related issue. Do you use bluetooth?
Is the package `firmware-atheros` installed? Check with `dpkg -l|grep firmware`...

https://packages.debian.org/de/jessie/firmware-atheros

#### Edit, regarding your new two-line output

Line 1 `Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M` shows the device that causes the error and that no driver is loaded. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide a clue as to what device it actually is. If your system works as expected, just ignore the message.

The second line *still* only shows a mount option and no actual error. You ignore it, it's a harmless piece of information.

Comment: I think firmware-atheros is not installed since there is no output of dpkg -l|grep firmware

Comment: edited, it remains to fix only the first line :)

Comment: sorry, just saw your edit now, I was not notified

Comment: actually the bluetooth is not working (or working stragely, like waking up randomly after lidl is open) may that be the device?